# Multiple actions for an HTML form

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make and HTML form post to 2 different php scripts. One is on my server and the other is on another. Basically I am trying to make it action="script1.php" action="script2.php" I am not sure if I can use my php script to forward the $_POST array to another php script. Let me know if you can help

Comment: You can NOT do this with html. a form tag has one action, and one action only. If you want to submit the form multiple times, you'll have to use javascript on the client and/or PHP on the server to do it for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use cURL to POST data to script2.php, from script1.php.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://whatever/script2.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($_POST);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Untested, but something like that should work for you.  See also:  http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl

http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Answer (score 1):

use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) on your php server to post the information to another server.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using javascript. You can have this form have a special class "DoubleAction" and then in javascript, you can check and post it the form to both actions, as in the following javascript sample:

```
if ( obj.hasClass('DoubleAction') ) {
        obj.submit(function() {


            var params = $(this).serialize(); 

            $.post( this.getAttribute("action"), params, clientData.ajaxLinksClient.complete );

            action2 = $(this).attr('action2');
            if ( typeof(action2) != 'undefined' && action2 != null && action2 != '' ) {
                $.post( action2, params );
            }
        });
    }
```